# How to place DIVs in rows and Column style

Tags: jquery, css, html

I was working on a structure where i need to place div in a manner as shown in the image.

[image]

with auto width but fixed height,not sure how to achieve it, the ideal HTML will be

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
<div class="box">4</div>
<div class="box">5</div>
<div class="box">6</div>

</div>
```

Comment: a good starting point would be .box {float:left;}

Comment: did you try anything?

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td><div>1</div></td>
<td><div>2</div></td>
<td><div>3</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td><div>4</div></td>
<td><div>5</div></td>
<td><div>6</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many grid systems already built and available for you to use. Most any of them will work to accomplish your goal. One that I like is [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com), but there's also Bootstrap, 960gs, 1140px, and more.

Take a look at http://www.1140px.com/ and see if it suits your needs. While you certainly could roll your own, using a framework for this means you get updates from the community instead of having to maintain it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a grid of 100% and divide them up between the boxes as such

```
.container {
  width:100%;
  background:blue;
}

.box-3 { 
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    min-height: 1px; 
    width: 30%;
    background:red;
}

.box-4 {
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    min-height:1px;
    width:40%;
    background:green;
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="box-3">1</div>
    <div class="box-3">3</div>
    <div class="box-4">5</div>
    <div class="box-3">2</div>
    <div class="box-4">4</div>
    <div class="box-3">6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a clearfix to clear the styles and start over. This div is not visible. Check out the fiddle. In this case the container will automatically adjust to the size of your inner-divs.

```
<div class="container">

<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="box">4</div>
<div class="box">5</div>
<div class="box">6</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
border: 1px solid green;
width: auto;

}
.clearfix:after
{
visibility: hidden;
display: block;
height: 0;
clear: both;
}
.box
{
border: 1px solid black;
display: inline-block;
height: 120px;
width: 120px;
margin: 2px;
}
```

See a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gjeny/Kyd44/)